# No ripple effect on recycleview touch event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have implemented navigation drawer using `RecycleView`, but when I click on items, no ripple effect shown. My device is running API 22.

**fragment_navigation.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">


<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

**and my rows are:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_get" android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="asa"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve this?

Comment: what's your device's API version?

Comment: So did you apply material theme for you layout/item elements?
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: If you are sure that you are using a Material theme, or an appCompat theme and it still doesn't work try adding this line to the root of your row's layout `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: when i click on items there is no select effect, so theme not  a answer

Comment: @user3106978, thanks your suggestion worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as your **Row** layout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true">

 <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_get"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="asa"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure why more people did not find this useful, it really saved a couple of hours.

Comment: so many people are posting other ways of selectableItemBackground but this is the only one that worked for me!