# Can't see click ripple effect in Android Touch events

Tags: android, user-interface, ontouchlistener, android-gesture, rippledrawable

I've seen some solutions here, but none of them works for me. I am using `View.OnTouchListener` class to detect click and drag events in my app code. But that beautiful ripple effect is now gone (perhaps because I am consuming the `MotionEvent` gestures before it gets to the `View.OnClickListener`. Notice the `return true` in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` block).

I cannot use `View.OnClickListener` to detect click events because my app uses multiple composite gestures (click, click-hold, click-hold-drag, etc). Can anyone please share some pointers on how to create ripple effect with Android touch gestures?

Here is the code snippet for my `View.OnTouchListener` implementation inside a `BaseAdapter` class:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if(mAppActionDownListener != null) {
                            mAppActionDownListener.onAppActionDown(appObjectList.get(position), v);
                        }
                        Log.d("COOK", "ACTION_DOWN: " + ev.getX() + ", " + ev.getY());
                        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("COOK", "ACTION_UP: " + ev.getX() + ", " + ev.getY());
                        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if(Math.abs(t2-t1) <=300) {
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Click event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(mAppClickListener!=null) {
                                mAppClickListener.onAppClicked(appObjectList.get(position), v);
                            }
                        }

                        return false;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("COOK", "ACTION_MOVE: " + ev.getX() + ", " + ev.getY());

                        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(appObjectList.get(position).getAppname()+"~"+appObjectList.get(position).getPackagename()+"~"+appObjectList.get(position).getAppicon());
                        ClipData dragData = new ClipData(
                                (CharSequence) v.getTag(),
                                new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN},
                                item);
                        v.findViewById(R.id.appicondrawable).startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                                new View.DragShadowBuilder(v.findViewById(R.id.appicondrawable)),  // the drag shadow builder
                                null,      // no need to use local data
                                0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
                        );

                        if(mAppDragListener!=null) {
                            mAppDragListener.onAppDragged(appObjectList.get(position), v);
                        }

                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;

                }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1:**

Just to clarify, setting up background/foreground/clickable attributes in the parent custom layout has no effect for reasons mentioned above. I have already tried those solutions.

**Update 2:**

Adding the adapter item layout code.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/applayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appicondrawable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="40dp"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="app name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your layout code as well.

Comment: Please see update 2 above. I've added android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true" in the root view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a way around this. Although the ripple effect is not customisable, the fix is pretty nifty. I manually called the `setPressed()` method on `View` inside the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events and now I can see the default Android ripple effect.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //icon.setColorFilter(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
                        v.setPressed(true);
                        if(mAppActionDownListener != null) {
                            mAppActionDownListener.onAppActionDown(appObjectList.get(position), v);
                        }
                        Log.d("COOK", "ACTION_DOWN: " + ev.getX() + ", " + ev.getY());
                        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.setPressed(false);
                        Log.d("COOK", "ACTION_UP: " + ev.getX() + ", " + ev.getY());
                        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if(Math.abs(t2-t1) <=300) {
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Click event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(mAppClickListener!=null) {
                                mAppClickListener.onAppClicked(appObjectList.get(position), v);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: worth noting that there is also `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` and it may occur INSTEAD `ACTION_UP`, so in that case `setPressed(false)` should also be called

Answer (score 1):

You need custom background or foreground to the layout.

Create a file named `res/drawable/ripple_selector.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"><color android:color="#dcffffff"/></item>
</ripple>
```

Then, use it as `background`:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/applayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_selector"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5sp">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

If does not work, try using it as `foreground`:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/applayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_selector"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5sp">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have also tried this before, and it didn't work either. Tried both background and foreground. Is there a way to create it directly inside the onTouch method?

Comment: I don't know. You can try that. @VinitShandilya

Answer (score 0):

to add a ripple effect to your view, you can add `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as view's background.

```
<ImageView
     android:height="100dp"
     android:width="100dp"
     android:src="@drawable/crush"
     android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work for me. I believe the attributes will work only for onclicklistener.

Comment: have you try to wrap your view as children and set the parent view's background to selectableItemBackground ?. see other references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964407/8109202, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268525/8109202

Comment: Yes, tried that as well. The point is, the gesture call is not getting to onclick event, which actually displays the ripple effect.

Comment: You right if you use onClickListener but doesn´t work if you use gesture detector